# How to fit a large numpy matrix with XGboost?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I have a `(878048, 9)` numpy array, which actually is a feature matrix. I would like to use XGboost python implementation in a supervised classification problem.

When I try to fit the data:

```
clf = XGBClassifier().fit(X, y)
```

It obviously will take a lot of time to finish. However, from this question I read that it is possible to fit large amouts of data by fitting the data in chunks. So far, I have not found an example of how to correctly pass numpy chunks to a classifier. Therefore, my question is **how to fit by chunks a numpy array with XGboost?**

Comment: I also know that there are classifiers like SGDC that support the `partial_fi()` function. However, I would like know which if there are other alternatives.

Comment: Can you provide the link to the question you reference that makes you think that you can train xgboost this way?

Comment: Thanks for the help @Tchotchke, which way?... the example or by chunks?

Comment: How much RAM do you have? If you can fit it into memory, you probably should.